# Is it possible to edit Babel transpiled files in Chrome devtools workspace?

Tags: ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

Dragging a local folder of files into the devtools adds them to the workspace so that you can persistently edit them. I just discovered the feature. However my files are all Babel transpiled and then I edit a file and hit cmd-s to save the changes Chrome checks the source and trips over es6 import statements with the error: `Unexpected token import`

Is there a way to make chrome not check the syntax? If it just edited the file without trying to compile it, Babel could pick it up and inject the changes via hot module replacement probably.

Comment: I have the same issue even if *Experimental JavaScript* flag is enabled (chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony)

Comment: Did you find a way to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried Canary? I posted a link to a video where this is demoed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently watched this presentation named ["Debugging the Web"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HF1luRD4Qmk) on the new Chrome devtools. At around 15mins he talks about this subject.

Before you could make it work with proper configuration. With this update it should work out of the box!

Comment: I couldn't pick it up from the video. Is there a solution to the issue?